# Combining Border's and Div Tag

Tags: html, tags, border

If I wanted to print out some text in div Tag could I implement a border into this or would I need to have a border line of code outside of the Div Tag and have the Div Tag in between. Or could I combine a Div Tag with a border

Comment: Hi, can you explain it better, please? To be honest, your question is a bit confusing. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Possible solution

**Your question was a bit confusing, maybe for me? Anyways, I don't know if is this what you wanted, but if it is, you are welcome!**

### Implement border inside a <div> tag

Firstly you need to set `border-box` to your `div` tag. This means you have to include different CSS code for browsers, such as `-moz`, or `-webkit`. Obviously you have to specify the `height` and `width` to your object, as well as **border** and **background** colour. You can also set the `margin`, but it's **not necessary**.

*Your code should look like this:*

### HTML

```
<!-- You can put even <p> tag, or any text tag into div -->
<div>
  Some text... 
</div>
```

### CSS

```
 div {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100px; /* Set your div width */
        height: 100px; /* Set your div height */
        border: 10px solid red; /* Optional amount for border, as well as colour*/
        background: #d9dbda;
        margin: 10px; /* This is optional */
      }
```

**If you want to see this sample in your browser, [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/cLj0foa6/).**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to underline text, you should probably opt for `text-decoration: underline;`

```css
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<p class="underline">This sentence has a line</p>
<p>Only <span class="underline">part of this sentence</span> has a line</p>
```

`.

But since I'm not quitte sure what it is you want to accomplish yet and you've asked for styling with borders with other elements (maybe for borders/lines at the top or on the side, or for different styling purposes). I'll add another example with a border. This will also be make it easier to style with different colors, width, etc

```css
.solid-border{
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid ;
  border-bottom-style: solid ;
}
```

```html
<div class="solid-border">
  <p>So just some lines for this sentence right?</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Or maybe just a <span class="solid-border">small part with lines like</span> this?</p>
</div>
```